# Send struct via UDP without serialization

Tags: c++, qt, networking, qudpsocket

I would like to send a struct :

```
typedef struct myStruct
    {
       int nb_trame;
       bool tabBool[20];
    } myStruct;
```

via a QUpdSocket.

I would like to not serialize it (so please no answer with `QDataStream`... ^^).

Will this work ? :

```
myStruct a;
//set a variable
mySocket->writeDatagram( (const char*) &a, sizeof(a), someQHostAddress, somePort);
```

Comment: @MikeCAT and how do I do it then ?

Comment: We won't be able to tell whether this will work without seeing declaration of `mySocket` and the type of it.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Due to padding, you can't simply take the address and the size of the struct.
You will need to also supply a pragma for packing.
This would be a compiler extension.

For example, in GCC:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed))
{
    int nb_trame;
    bool tabBool[20];
} myStruct;
```